# ¿Qué es la autenticación LDAP?

Tags: autenticación, directorioactivo, ldap

He de implementar la autenticación LDAP para las aplicaciones que se manejan en la compañía. Estas aplicaciones se venden a los clientes, los cuáles, han pedido poder autenticarse mediante ese protocolo.

He estado leyendo acerca de LDAP pero no logro entender la diferencia entre un logueo convencional, es decir, almacenar usuario y contraseña en una DB a hacerlo mediante LDAP, que según he leído y entiendo, es lo mismo.

Por otro lado, según entiendo, con LDAP se busca autenticar mediante usuario de red. eso quiere decir que;

- ¿Solo quien inicie sesión en un pc con su usuario y contraseña de red, podrá autenticarse a la aplicación?
- ¿Si me logueo con usuario de red, nadie más puede loguearse a la aplicación desde la sesión activa?

Realmente no entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento de LDAP. Agradecería orientación en el tema.

Gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta se basa mas en una opinión que en una pregunta

Comment: aqui te dejo un pequeño tutorial https://www.linuxito.com/programacion/1031-autenticacion-con-ldap-en-php. En teoria LDAP recuerdo cuando lo estudie que se utiliza cuando tienes servidores de usuarios, por ejemplo en el servidor de la empresa tienen un sistema activo de usuarios y sirve para entrar a la aplicacion con el mismo sistema de usuarios que recoge desde el propio servidor

Comment: Hola, te sugiero revisa [ask] y realizar el [tour] del sitio.

Comment: Básicamente LDAP en GNU/Linux y en Windows: Active Directory. Te piden que se autentiquen por medio de credenciales a nivel de servidor. Esto puede generar acceso interno o externo dependiendo de cómo sea la arquitectura de la red donde te encuentras y cómo esté configurado el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP es un protocolo que usan los servidores para comunicar y verificar la identidad un usario, nada más.  Solo es un protocol de autenticación.  Lo que se puede ver o hacer son temas de autorización, que vive afuera del mundo de LDAP.  LDAP determina quien es, no lo que se puede.

Para los usarios, la diferencia entre un logueo convencional y LDAP no les importan.  Tampoco con los programas, hay llamadas de API diferentes, pero lo que pasa entre servidores no le importa a la aplicación.  Un beneficio de LDAP es que todas las aplicaciones puede compartir credentiales y por eso el usario no necesita cuentas para cada aplicación.